# Recycler view items auto wrapping inside scrollview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am a newbie to android. I have Recyclerview implemented inside NestedScrollView. When I press next everything works fine, but when I return to the previous item it just wraps itself.
I have tried everything possible to make it work.

Following is the code.

**For the Next & previous question, on pressing respective  the following code executes**

[image]

**QuizAttemptFragment.xml.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".view.fragments.QuizAttemptFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/clQuiz"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFeedBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
            tools:text="Feedback"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:drawablePadding="4dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_comment_black"
            android:drawableTint="@color/blackColor"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAssignmentStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
            tools:text="Marked"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvQuestionNum"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:listitem="@layout/layout_num"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvQuestionDet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbFragmentListLoading"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/yellowThemeColor"
            android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.526"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDur"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_clock_blck"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="DD:HH:MM"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.089"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="98dp" />


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvQuestionNew"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:minHeight="300dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/rlNav"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDur"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            tools:listitem="@layout/user_question" />

        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableTint="@color/blackColor"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:text="Previous"
            android:textColor="@color/blackColor"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ImageButton
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:id="@+id/ibFlag"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_flag"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNext"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableTint="@color/blackColor"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="@color/blackColor"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cvSubmit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:minWidth="80dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvBtnCreateAssignmentSubmit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#584056"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
                    android:text="Submit"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**layout_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#fcfbfc"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPoint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_light"
            android:textColor="@color/blackColor"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="10 Points" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlheader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblques"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_light"
                android:textColor="@color/blackColor"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                tools:text="15." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvQuestion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/edPoint"
                android:minLines="2"
                tools:text="Who from the following is responsible for this question"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/blackColor" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPoint"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_light"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/blackColor"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:text="/10" />

            <EditText

                android:id="@+id/edPoint"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_light"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:inputType="number"
                tools:text="100"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tvPoint"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/blackColor" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlAnswer"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_square"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <TextView
                   android:padding="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/edAnswer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    tools:text="assfadasffdsdfddfd"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/blackColor" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llOptions"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:clickable="false"
                android:id="@+id/llOpt1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbOpt1"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/darkGreyColor"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:clickable="false"
                android:id="@+id/llOpt2"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbOpt2"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/darkGreyColor"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/llOpt3"

                android:clickable="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbOpt3"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/darkGreyColor"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/llOpt4"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbOpt4"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/darkGreyColor"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/cvDocPreview"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/llCreateAssignmentParent1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/whiteColor"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                            android:id="@+id/cardImage"
                            app:cardElevation="0dp"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/ivPreviewItem"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:minHeight="60dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_file_black"
                                android:background="@color/thumbnail_background"
                                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                                android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
                        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardImage"
                            android:id="@+id/llFileUpload"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvFileNameItem"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:letterSpacing="0.02"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                                android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                tools:text="Filename.ext" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tvFileType"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:letterSpacing="0.02"
                                    android:textColor="#000000"
                                    android:textSize="12sp"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:ellipsize="end"
                                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
                                    tools:text="File Type" />

                                <View
                                    android:id="@+id/viewDivide"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:background="@color/black_half"
                                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp"/>


                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tvFileSize"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:letterSpacing="0.02"
                                    android:textColor="#000000"
                                    android:textSize="12sp"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:ellipsize="end"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
                                    android:text="24 mb" />



                            </LinearLayout>


                        </LinearLayout>



                        <ImageButton
                            android:padding="7dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            android:id="@+id/ibDownloadItem"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                            android:background="@color/whiteColor"
                            android:tint="@color/blackColor"
                            android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_download" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNotAttempted"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Question not attempted"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/redWarningColor"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMandatory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Mandatory Question*"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/redWarningColor"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Before Pressing Next**
[image]

**Returning to the previous item it just wraps views**

[image]

Please help, I am stuck for 2 weeks

Comment: Can you attach a video or gif for a clear understanding of current behaviour?

Comment: can you also share the code triggered by pressing Next/Previous?

Comment: @Stachu Updated the code, StackOverflow does not allow more than 30000 characters so added image.